# No Activity found to handle Intent Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin android application and i want to open a pdf file.After the last line of the code i got the error

> Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=/storage/emulated/0/docen__.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x80000 }

```
 Stream _IS = this.Assets.Open("doc" + GlobalsAndroid.FixedDocumentationLanguageCode + ".pdf");
                                        byte[] _BA = null;
                                        using (BinaryReader _BR = new BinaryReader(_IS))
                                        {
                                            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                                            {
                                                byte[] _buffer = new byte[4096];
                                                int count;
                                                while ((count = _BR.Read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length)) != 0)
                                                    ms.Write(_buffer, 0, count);
                                                _BA = ms.ToArray();
                                            }
                                        }

                                        string _EP = System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "doc" + GlobalsAndroid.FixedDocumentationLanguageCode + "__.pdf");
                                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_EP, _BA);

                                        Intent _I = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                                        _I.SetDataAndType(global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse(_EP), "application/pdf");
                                        _I.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                                        _I.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                                        _I.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);

                                        this.StartActivity(_I);
```

My manifest is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.3" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
    <application   android:debuggable="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

</manifest>
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some changes it works.

```
    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "doc" + GlobalsAndroid.FixedDocumentationLanguageCode + ".pdf");
                                               
    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                                                
    global::Android.Net.Uri pdfFile = 
    global::Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(path));
    intent.SetDataAndType(pdfFile, "application/pdf");
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);
                                          
    this.StartActivity(intent);
```